# How to read a parquet file with arrays by ROW instead of array elements?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-io

I am using tensorflow-io to read a parquet file. This parquet file contains columns with lists or maps. Following is an example of my dataset in duck db, as you can see, there is a timestamp column and two array columns.

[image]

I am using the following function to load the file. I uses tensorflow-io (version 0.36, compatible with tensorflow 2.15).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

def load_single_parquet_file(source_file_path: str, relevant_features_list: Optional[List[str]]) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    single_file_dataset = tfio.IODataset.from_parquet(source_file_path, columns=relevant_features_list)
    return single_file_dataset
```

I need the rows as is, that means, a timestamp (may be in any other tensorflow-compatible format) and two 1-dimensional tensors of type string. But the function is retuning me a dataset where each row a cartesian product of the elements of the array, that means, it is reading at array element level instead of row level, what makes no sense to my problem and make the data unusable.

Here is a piece of the output:

```
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700691007000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'91.25'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700691080000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'85.62'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700691293000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'80.12'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700691670000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'70.12'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700691881000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'60.12'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700856196000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'60.12'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700858022000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'85.12'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700859164000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'85.12'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700861186000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'80.00'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700862391000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'75.00'>)])
```

As you can see, it's repeating the `previous_scores.list.element` for the same values of `timestamp` and `device_type.list.element`, instead of just returning the lists.

How can I read a parquet file with nested structures by-row, not by row element?

I am using tensorflow-io to read a parquet file. This parquet file contains columns with lists or maps. Following is an example of my dataset in duck db, as you can see, there is a timestamp column and two array columns.

[image]

I am using the following function to load the file. I uses tensorflow-io (version 0.36, compatible with tensorflow 2.15).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

def load_single_parquet_file(source_file_path: str, relevant_features_list: Optional[List[str]]) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    single_file_dataset = tfio.IODataset.from_parquet(source_file_path, columns=relevant_features_list)
    return single_file_dataset
```

I need the rows as is, that means, a timestamp (may be in any other tensorflow-compatible format) and two 1-dimensional tensors of type string. But the function is retuning me a dataset where each row a cartesian product of the elements of the array, that means, it is reading at array element level instead of row level, what makes no sense to my problem and make the data unusable.

Here is a piece of the output:

```
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700691007000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'91.25'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700691080000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'85.62'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700691293000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'80.12'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700691670000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'70.12'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700691881000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'60.12'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700856196000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'60.12'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700858022000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'85.12'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700859164000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'85.12'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700861186000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'80.00'>)])
OrderedDict([(b'timestamp', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1700862391000000>), (b'device_type.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'desktop'>), (b'previous_scores.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'75.00'>)])
```

As you can see, it's repeating the `previous_scores.list.element` for the same values of `timestamp` and `device_type.list.element`, instead of just returning the lists.

How can I read a parquet file with nested structures by-row, not by row element?